# Making a canonical post that needs way too many tags

Tags: discussion, tags, canonical

A few weeks back, I made a canonical post about [shader invocation frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243518/frequency-of-shader-invocations-in-rendering-commands). I tagged it with the tags I thought were appropriate at the time.

However as I think about it now, the question/answer itself is appropriate for a lot more tags than just that. The information is applicable to:

- [webgl]
- [mantle]
- [metal]
- [vulkan]

And possibly more, depending on how loose you want to be.

See, the Q&A is *really* about the underlying hardware and how it works. The multitude of different 3D APIs all have the same answer because they're just ways of accessing that same hardware. The problem is that *users* don't think in terms of "hardware". They'd be asking about the particular API they're using to access it.

So what tags should this question use so that users will actually be able to find this information?

Comment: Meh, I wouldn't lose too much sleep over it. Canonical questions are still incredibly useful for tag experts to use as dupe-targets. Lots of askers don't know enough background information to find them, and just don't spend enough time trying before hitting the submit button. Be sure to add links to these tag wikis, at least the experienced users can find them that way.

Comment: In your specific case, if the question truly is about the hardware and not the APIs, then I sure wouldn't tag it with any of them.

Comment: I normally go by 95% of relevance or more... kind of answering: if this question can only have one tag, which one would that be?

Comment: You can also mention the extra tags in the question text itself where you don't have the cap of 5, and that might help people find it.

Comment: Use the five tags most likely to be used when trying to find that answer, *or*, use the five tags most relevant to the answer.